Can objects be replaced in GridDB through SQL/TQL?
I have numerous tables and views created in GridDB that are constantly changing and being recreated.
I'm having to drop and recreate each of them because the "or replace" statement in the create script doesn't work, for example:
CREATE or REPLACE TABLE myTable (
   Date TIMESTAMP PRIMARY KEY,
   FirstColumn BOOL NOT NULL,
   SecondColumn VARCHAR NOT NULL
 );

Throws the following error
D20332: An unexpected error occurred while executing a SQL. : msg=[[240001:SQL_COMPILE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Parse SQL failed, reason = Syntax error at or near "or" (line=1, column=7) on updating (sql="create or REPLACE TABLE myTable

I don't see the "or replace" statement mentioned in the GridDB documentation, so I assume it's not part of the ecosystem or it is restricted to certain objects.
Is there a way to replace objects in GridDB? Either in SQL or TQL
Thank you!
